Security risks of using a daily driver as a samba server?
I've currently got three machine at my disposal for use as my daily driver. A Lenovo ThinkPad X1 carbon 6th generation, an hp Z420 work station and an Hp ChromeBook.
Is it a significant security risk to use my HP Z420 as both a SAMBA server as well as a "daily driver" if i don't open it up to the out side world? Or should I consider saving up and phasing something like a Intel NUC in as my Workstation and wait until then to configure the HP Z420 as the samba server?

It depends on your distro.
Samba has had a ton of 0-day remote root vulnerabilities.
Subscribe to Samba CVEs and security mailing lists and patch it as soon as humanly possible. Otherwise it is quite risky indeed.

I'm running Debian on both the workstation and Laptop and ChromeOs on the Chrome Book as well as Android 15 Vanilla  Ice Cream  on my Google Pixel 6 Pro.
